# Email link not clickable in HTML Email php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I send a email with php form. And I have the field "message" when user type link and submit form email send via html/text but link no active. How to set link be active?

```
 $body = '<html><body>';
 $body .= '<table width="770" border="1">';
 $body .= '<tr><th colspan="2" bgcolor="#4e604a" scope="col" style="color: white">Order</th></tr>';
 $body .= '<tr><td width="91" align="center" bgcolor="#D6D6D6"><strong>Name:</strong></td><td width="663"> ' . $name . ' </td></tr>';
 $body .= '<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#D6D6D6"><strong>Email:</strong></td><td> ' .$email . ' </td></tr>';
 $body .= '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#4E604A" style="color: white"><strong>Message:</strong></td></tr>';
 $body .= '<tr><td colspan="2" style="word-wrap: 80px"><pre style="font-size: 14px">' . $message . ' </pre></td></tr>';
 $body .= '</table>';
 $body .= '</body></html>';
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [fotkica.com](http://fotkica.com/imgs3/1_241329065_stack.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Please post the $message variable contents. Are you wrapping your links within <a> elements? Are you sending your messages in plain text?

Comment: no message sending with html

$mailer->isHTML(TRUE); // set email format to HTML

$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : FALSE;

how wrapping links within <a> ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to write [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) in HTML:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816048/">This is a link</a>
```

Note that you are also printing your `$message` variable inside a [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), which is for pre-formatted text, so you can't make links inside there anyway.

Comment: I know but user when come to my site HE not type <a href= etc...

HE or SHE type only link 

http://blabla.com

Comment: You aren't typing on a user's browser. You're writing an HTML document and emailing it.

Comment: My php form send me no clickable links. See picture on my first post.

I want active clickable links...